# How to access resource id from anonymous inner class method?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

- I created a new project with empty activity selected.
- Then I added a new layout file called `layout_extra.xml` with `id` of `layout_extra` and it just contains one switch with `id` of `switch1`.
- The `activity_main.xml` contains a button with `id` of `button` to navigate to the `layout_extra`.
- The content of `MainActivity.java` is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(v->{
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_extra);
        });

        findViewById(R.id.switch1).setOnClickListener(v->{
            findViewById(R.layout.layout_extra).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        });
    }
}
```

## Question

I got the following error on the Android  Studio.

[image]

The tooltip gives the following info.

[image]

I did all the given suggestions but none works (the application crashes).

How to properly call resource id from within an anonymous class method?

Comment: The above code is a trivial yet minimal example to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have got the error. You are calling `setOnClickListener()` on a null object. Hence, the updated code should be:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // The following does not set the layout 'layout_extra' as root view until the button press
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(v->{
            // This block executes on button press
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_extra);
            final View layout_extra = findViewById(R.id.layout_extra);
            
            findViewById(R.id.switch1).setOnClickListener(v2->{
                layout_extra.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

where `R.id.layout_extra` refers to the `id` of the root element of `layout_extra.xml`.

Comment: Could you post some portion of your exception log?

Comment: `final View layout_extra = findViewById(R.id.layout_extra);` is optional because we can actually invoke `findViewById(R.id.layout_extra).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);` from the second lambda. It is just for my note in the future visit. :-)

Comment: Yes, it is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Hum, the method "findViewById()" is asking the ID of the Object not the Resource.

Basically what i believe you should do is set the "ID" in the "XML" of your main layout, than you can use the method "findViewById()", any object has an id in "XML" even the layout can be set an ID.

Ex:
Set in the XML the id of you main object:

> android:id="@+id/layout_extra"

in the code:

> findViewById(R.id.layout_extra).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

Comment: Your answer partially solved my problem. It means that I have to add `id` to the root element of `layout_extra.xml`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The setOnClickListener() use a new view so `findViewById(R.layout.layout_extra).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);` didn't work, you should try :

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Layout layout_extra; // TextView, Button ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(v->{
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_extra);
        });

        layout_extra = findViewById(R.layout.layout_extra);

        findViewById(R.id.switch1).setOnClickListener(v->{
            layout_extra.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `layout_extra = findViewById(R.layout.layout_extra);` does not compile. They are from different type. Cannot cast from `View` to `Layout`.

Comment: So write : `private View layout_extra; ` @LetMeBeYourLostDisciple

Comment: Sorry. It does not work at all. Thank you very much for your participation!